# Chaotic dynamical systems with hard proposition

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

How I can prove this proposition ?

proposition : Consider a network with a fixed connection topology, having
in each node identical members of the family of m-modal functions f in
the real interval. Then:

1)The synchronizability decreases when the topological entropy $ h_{top}(f) $, in
each node, increases

2)There is a threshold value $h_0$ of the topological entropy $h_{top}(f) $ such that

for each f in this family, with topological entropy $ h<h_0 $ the synchronization
interval of the network with f in each node is nonempty.

I would be interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: Hi: welcome to the internet! Please do not use all caps, not even for titles! Thanks. (Edit: the post was since edited)

Comment: thank you very much for improving my question, just i want to know how i can using a semiconjugacy to prove this proof , thanks

Comment: Dear @rafik : a few other things. Traditionally you can put "*Proof:*" right before you write justification for a statement, but it is confusing to put it at the beginning of the statement. "*Proposition:*" is a good alternative. Finally, proofs are not the thing proven, but rather they are what is doing the proving (through you, of course). *How can I prove this proposition?* is a good alternative.